# use variable in postgresql's stored procedure to for adding a partition

Tags: postgresql, procedure

i need to add a new partition in stored procedure, and a varialbe need to be used, the code is as follows:

```
create or replace procedure modifyPartition()
as
declare 
 nextDate date;
begin
 nextDate :=date_trunc('hour',sysdate);
 alter table TB_MOVIL_CDR add partition ***** values less than (nextDate);
end;
/
```

but i get the following error:

ERROR: column "nextDate" does not exists, what's the reason ? can we use varialbe in "alter table" command ?

Comment: Are you sure you are using Postgres? Neither the procedure definition nor the ALTER TABLE statement are valid for Postgres - that code will result in a completely different error message (plus: Postgres has no `sysdate`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need dynamic SQL for that.

But there is a lot more that is wrong with your procedure.

There is no `sysdate` in Postgres, you have to use `current_date` and there is no need to remove "hours" from it, because a `date` in Postgres does not contain any time part.

`alter table` is not the way to create a new partition in Postgres. [As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html#SQL-CREATETABLE-PARTITION) you need to create a table that is a partition.

`values less than` is also not valid to define a (range) partition in Postgres. A range partitioned table needs a start and end date for the partition values. So you need to calculate two dates, not just one. Assuming you want to create a partition for the current month, you could do something like this:

```
create or replace procedure modify_partition()
as
$$
declare 
  l_partname text;
  l_part_start date; 
  l_part_end date;
  l_sql text;
begin
  l_part_start = date_trunc('month', current_date)::date;
  l_part_end = (date_trunc('month', current_date) + interval '1 month')::date;
  l_partname := 'movil_cdr_part_'||to_char(current_date, 'yyyy_mm');

  l_sql := format('CREATE TABLE %I PARTITION OF tb_movil_cdr 
    FOR VALUES FROM (%L) TO (%L)', l_partname, l_part_start, l_part_end);

  execute l_sql;
end;
$$
language plpgsql;
```

`format()` is the preferred way to create SQL for dynamic SQL. The placeholder `%I` will properly deal with identifiers. And `%L` will properly deal with literals.